# What does python itertools recipe consume() mean at all?

Tags: python, iterator

I was learning the itertools through python docs:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

And at the very end there are recipes that use itertools commands to do simple things, one of them, the consume(), I don't understand it at all:

```
from itertools import *
def consume(iterator, n):
    """"Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is none, consume 
        entirely."""
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)
```

first of all, this function claims argument to be an iterator, but I found that an iterable will do as well. I think there is a difference between iterable and iterator, right? Because `islice()` needs no iterator, an iterable could be used

Secondly, When I tried it:

```
aa = iter([1,2,3,4,5])
print(consume(aa, 2))
```

it give me `None`, because `islice(iterator, n, n)` will always be `None` no matter what, as (n, n) has no range to be sliced.

And of course if `n` is `None`, then I will definitely get `None`
So it seems like no matter what I do here, I get `None` as the output anyway, what is the purpose of this function at all?

Comment: *"but I found that an iterable will do as well"* - Why does that surprise you? It's *meant* to be used with an iterator, but an iterable doesn't break it either. *"islice(iterator, n, n) will always be None"* - It will be an empty iterator, that is different from `None`. *"it give me None"* - Because the function doesn't return *anything*. *"what is the purpose of this function at all?"* - Read the docstring.

Comment: If it always returns `None`, that strongly suggests it's not being used for its return value, right? Think about the side effects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`consume` is not supposed to return anything useful.  Like the docs says, its purpose is to advance the existing iterator.  If you look at `aa` after your example, you will see it has been advanced:

```
>>> aa = iter([1,2,3,4,5])
... print(consume(aa, 2))
None
>>> next(aa)
3
```

Because the use of `consume` is in its side effect, you can use it on an a "re-iterable" object, but doing so will be useless.  What happens is that `islice` will create an iterator over the object, and advance that iterator, but that won't affect subsequent iteration over the iterable, because a new iterator will be created:

```
# consuming an iterator
aa = iter([1,2,3,4,5])
consume(aa, 2)
print(list(aa))
# [3, 4, 5]

# "consuming" an iterable
aa = [1,2,3,4,5]
consume(aa, 2)
print(list(aa))
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

In the latter case, all you consumed was a temporary iterator that was created inside `consume` itself but not returned, so it had no observable effect.

(I use the term "re-iterable" to refer to iterable objects which generate a "fresh" iterator over some stable base data each time `iter` is called.  Lists, for instance, are re-iterables.  Every re-iterable object is iterable, but you can write an iterable object which is not re-iterable.)

Comment: ah!! Got it!! That is what it means! They really should have put an example there so beginners like me can understand...

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. This is the first time I saw a function that is used for its side effect. Very educating, and enlightening.

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 I doubt this is the first function you've seen used for it's side effect. `print` is a function that is used for it's side-effect, and of course, many list-methods do just that, e.g. `.append`. Note, both `.append` and `print` return `None`

Answer (score 2):

Iterating through a list is kind of pointless unless you do something with its elements, but advancing through an iterator can execute code; for example, you might be iterating through the values returned by a function with side effects. `consume()` walks through several elements and throws them away. The general idea (if you don't consume everything) is that it works like `seek()` in a file handle: When you try to get something out of the iterator afterwards, you will be at a different position.

Comment: I guess that is why the function calls for an iterator now, because when I use the next() on aa after consuming the first 2 elements, it needs to be an iterator other than an iterable.